# How to save colors so that they will be loaded when my R package loads

Tags: r, package

I'd like to start including custom color labels in my R package

```
my_orange <- '#ff6901'
my_purple <- '#6f54a3'
my_green <- '#53b647'
my_dark_green <- '#118482'
```

What is a practical place and file format to save these colors so that they are loaded into the environment when my package is loaded?